NAS OS hard drives failed; Bring "volume 2" Raid 1 back on a new OS install
I have an Asustor NAS. I had four hard drives in it. The OS was installed on a Raid 0 configuration comprising two 500 GB hard drives. That became volume 1.
I then created volume 2 consisting of two 4 GB hard drives in Raid 1 configuration. This is the volume/data I want to bring back up.
I've replaced the Raid 0 500 GB hard drive with a new 4 TB hard drive (just one, no RAID). It's installed and running fine. (One of the 500 GBs drives failed so the previous OS install is gone.)
The question is how do I get that Old Volume 2 going again? Both hard drives that made up the "RAID 1 volume 2" configuration are in the NAS but are seen as "inactive".
How can I make them active and read the file system? The only option offered is the standard create-volume which re-formats them (I think).
How can I get Volume 2 going and get my data?
